# Using Substring to get digit before a string

Tags: c#

I am reading a file in C#. I want to check value from a string. The line consists as following:

```
   15  EMP_L_NAME HAPPENS 5 TIMES.   
   40  SUP HAPPENS 12 TIMES.
```

I want to find the number of times which is in the string before the string "TIMES". I have written the following code:

```
     int arrayLength = 0;
     int timesindex = line.IndexOf("TIMES"); 
     if (timesindex > 0)
     {
          //Positon of the digit "5" in the first line
          int indexCount = timesindex - 2;
          if (int.TryParse(line.Substring(indexCount, 1), out occursCount)) 
          {
                  arrayLength = occursCount;
           }
      }
```

Using the above code, I can find the number of "TIMES" for a single digigt number. But if it is a double digit, it won't work( e.g the second line). I have to develop a logic to find the digit which is separted by a space with "TIMES". How I can do that?

Comment: You have to find the end of `HAPPENS` and the beginning of `TIMES`. Get the value in between and use `trim()` to get rid of the spaces. And there ya go

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

- Split your string on space and remove empty enteries.
- Find Index of "TIMES."
- Access element Index - 1

Like:

```
string str = "15  EMP_L_NAME HAPPENS 5 TIMES. ";
string[] array = str.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

int index = Array.IndexOf(array, "TIMES.");

int number;
if (!int.TryParse(array[index - 1], out number))
{
    //invalid number
}
Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is reliable you can do a quicky with `String.Split()`...

```
int arrayLength = 0;
int timesindex = line.IndexOf("TIMES"); 
if (timesindex > 0)
{
    string[] items = line.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (int.TryParse(items[items.Length - 2], out occursCount)) 
    {
        arrayLength = occursCount;
    }
}
```

This method relies on the desired number being the second from last "word" in each line

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are always the same format, with exactly five words or "sections" or whatever you want to call them, you could use:

```
int times = 0;
Int32.TryParse(line.Split(' ')[3], out times);
```

This would have to be more robust there's a chance the number may not exist in the string, or the string is in a completely different format.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc3z4t9d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) combined with your `timesindex`. You can look for the space before the space before (`timesindex`-1), and then you have the two positions around the number.

```
int timesindex = line.IndexOf("TIMES");
int firstSpace = line.LastIndexOf(" ", timesindex-1);
string number = line.Substring(firstSpace, timesindex-firstSpace);
```

Though this might need some adjustments on the indexes, but that's the idea anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int timesindex = line.IndexOf("TIMES");
int happensindex = line.IndexOf("HAPPENS") + 7; //Add 7 cause HAPPEND is 7 chars long
if (timesindex > 0)
{
    //Positon of the digit "5" in the first line
    if (int.TryParse(line.Substring(happensindex, timesindex).trim(), out occursCount)) 
    {
        arrayLength = occursCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`, i.e. a regular expression, in order to find a pattern in a string:

```
string input = "40  SUP HAPPENS 12 TIMES.";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=HAPPENS\s)\d+(?=\sTIMES)");
if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value); '==> "12"
}
```

Explanation of the regular expression: It uses the general pattern `(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)` in order to find a position between a prefix and suffix.

```
(?<=HAPPENS\s)      Prefix consisting of "HAPPENS" plus a whitespace (\s)
\d+                 A digit (\d) repeated one or more times (+)
(?=\sTIMES)         Suffix consisting of a whitespace (\s) plus "TIMES"
```

If you only want to test for "TIMES" but not for "HAPPENS", you can just drop the first part:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"\d+(?=\sTIMES)");
```

---

Since you are using the same search pattern many times, it is advisable to create a `Regex` once instead of calling a static method:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+(?=\sTIMES)");

// Use many times with different inputs
Match match = regex.Match(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

A Regex would be cleaner:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(\d+)\sTIMES");  // match a number followed by whitespace then "TIMES"
string num = regex.Match(" 15  EMP_L_NAME HAPPENS 5 TIMES").Groups[1].ToString();
int val = int.Parse(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
string[] lines = {"15  EMP_L_NAME HAPPENS 5,1 TIMES.", "40  SUP HAPPENS 12 TIMES. "};

var allValues = lines.Select(line =>
            {
                double temp;
                var words = line.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var value = words[Array.IndexOf(words,"TIMES.") - 1];
                if (double.TryParse(value, out temp)) return temp;
                else return 0;
            }).ToList();

            foreach (var value in allValues)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }  

// Output:
//   5,1
//   12
```